# How do I find the nth term of a sequence such that the sum of the terms add to a particular amount?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have the sum, which is 345, the first term, which is 12, and the common difference is 5, how do I find the number of terms that when summed will give me 345?

Comment: Do you mean 12+Sum[12+5*i,{i,1,k}]=345 and you want to find k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your example your first term is $a_1=12.$ The second term, $a_2=17=12+5.$ The third term is $a_3=22=12+5\cdot 2.$

So, if you add $n$ terms you have:

$$a_1+\cdots+a_n=12+12+5+\cdots + 12+(n-1)5.$$ That is,

$$12\cdot n+(1+\cdots+(n-1))5.$$ Now

$$1+2+\cdots +(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$ So

$$a_1+\cdots+a_n=12\cdot n+ 5\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=345.$$ So you only need to solve the quadratic equation

$$12\cdot n+ 5\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=345.$$ That is:

$$24\cdot n+ 5n^2-5n=690\Rightarrow 5n^2+19n-690=0,$$ which has solutions $n=10$ and $n=-\frac{69}{5}.$ We are only interested in integer (and positive) solutions. So $n=10.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}=n*(n+1)/2$ then the sum of $x+(x+a)+(x+a+a)+...+x(x+a*k)=x*(a+1)+(a)(k)(k+1)/2$, so

$12+(12+5)+(12+5+5)+...+(12+5*k)=12*(k+1)+(5)(k)(k+1)/2$

and this gives k=9